# Automatic, contained testing of a web app

Tags: spring, rest, testing, jersey, rest-assured

I have a web application that uses Spring, Jersey (for REST) and Hibernate+PostgreSQL. I'm using REST Assured for the testing framework. I created a simple test case and it works as long as I run Tomcat with my war.

I have a few questions regarding isolation & automatic tests:

1. I don't want to run tomcat just for the test. I would like to embed an app server.
2. I want to isolate my DB calls so that I can test it in a clean, predictable way.

Any suggestions, tips, links etc. for these challenges will be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You could use embedded Jetty as an embedded application server. Check out [this](http://kielczewski.eu/2013/11/using-embedded-jetty-spring-mvc/) and [this](http://steveliles.github.io/setting_up_embedded_jetty_8_and_spring_mvc_with_maven.html) post for details.
2. What you most likely want in this case is to run the application with a [Spring profile](http://www.captaindebug.com/2012/08/using-spring-profiles-and-java.html#.U0pJ9PmSwXw),
   in which profile the only thing that changes is the datasource. You would likely want to use an in-memory database like H2 or HSQL. Chek out [this](http://gordondickens.com/wordpress/2013/02/28/database-config-spring-3-2-environment-profiles/comment-page-1/) and [this](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.gr/2012/09/spring-3-javaconfig-unit-testing-using.html) post.